# replacing a string by a list value from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Ok back here again-

I have this dictionary -

This dictionary has been created after parsing a C file which consists of comments and C - structures,Hence for every comment enclosed b/w /**/ there is a value of structure associated with it.so the key value pair is /**/:{} (hope this make sense)

```
{'': [], '/* JOB_ATR_depend */': ['{ ATTR_c,\n\t\tREAD_WRITE', 'ATR_DFLAG_MOM', 'ATR_DFLAG_ALTRUN,\n                ATR_TYPE_STR,\n\t\tNULL_VERIFY_DATATYPE_FUNC,\n                verify_value_checkpoint\n\t},'], '/* ATTR_q */': ['{ ATTR_q,\n                 READ_WRITE', 'ATR_DFLAG_ALTRUN', 'ATR_DFLAG_SELEQ', 'ATR_DFLAG_MOM,\n                 ATR_TYPE_STR,\n                 NULL_VERIFY_DATATYPE_FUNC,\n                 NULL_VERIFY_VALUE_FUNC\n         },'], '/* JOB_ATR_array_indices_submitted */': ['{ ATTR_eligible_time,             \n\t\tNO_USER_SET', 'ATR_DFLAG_SSET', 'ATR_DFLAG_ALTRUN,\n                ATR_TYPE_LONG,\n\t\tverify_datatype_time,\n                NULL_VERIFY_VALUE_FUNC\n        },'], '/* JOB_ATR_eligible_time */': ['{ ATTR_u,\n\t\tREAD_WRITE', 'ATR_DFLAG_SELEQ', 'ATR_DFLAG_SCGALT,\n                ATR_TYPE_ARST,\n\t\tNULL_VERIFY_DATATYPE_FUNC,\n                verify_value_user_list\n        },'], '/* JOB_ATR_exec_host */': ['{ ATTR_depend,                   \n\t\tREAD_WRITE,\n                ATR_TYPE_LIST,\n\t\tNULL_VERIFY_DATATYPE_FUNC,\n                verify_value_dependlist\n\t},'], '/* JOB_ATR_userlst */': ['{ ATTR_a,\n\t\tREAD_WRITE', 'ATR_DFLAG_ALTRUN,\n                ATR_TYPE_LONG,\n\t\tverify_datatype_long,\n                NULL_VERIFY_VALUE_FUNC\n        },'], '/* JOB_ATR_exectime */': ['{ ATTR_exechost,          \n\t\tREAD_ONLY,\n\t\tATR_TYPE_STR,\n\t\tNULL_VERIFY_DATATYPE_FUNC,\n                NULL_VERIFY_VALUE_FUNC\n\t},'], '/* JOB_ATR_array_indices_remaining */': ['{ ATTR_array_indices_submitted,  \n\t\tATR_DFLAG_SvWR', 'ATR_DFLAG_SvRD', 'ATR_DFLAG_Creat', 'READ_ONLY,\n                ATR_TYPE_STR,\n\t\tNULL_VERIFY_DATATYPE_FUNC,\n                verify_value_jrange\n        },']}
```

Now i am reading a file like this -

```
 for i in temp_file
```

i.e processing the file line by line so whenever a comment is encountered like this

```
 if re.search('\/*',line)
```

I will go and check in the dictionary if this comment matches the key in my dictionary

```
 for i,j in dict.iteritems()
```

the comment gets replaced with its corresponding structure value {}

Example:For the key

```
 /* JOB_ATR_depend */
```

encountered in a file i will like it to be replaced with its corresponding value

```
{ ATTR_c,\n\t\tREAD_WRITE', 'ATR_DFLAG_MOM', 'ATR_DFLAG_ALTRUN,\n                    ATR_TYPE_STR,\n\t\tNULL_VERIFY_DATATYPE_FUNC,\n                verify_value_checkpoint\n\t},
```

Since strings are immutable in python how do i replace the string with a list?

Comment: How big is the file?  Would it be reasonable to read it all into memory?  If so, why would [`string.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) not work?

Comment: I see several strings in the dictionary. Which specific string do you want to replace with a list? (The syntax for adding a value for a key in a dictionary is `list[key] = value`.)

Comment: "how do I replace a string in a file with a list" is a meaningless question so it is quite unclear what you're asking.  Do you just want to replace the string with the first element of the list?  The `repr` of the list itself?  Something else?

Comment: @jedwards - string.replace will not work coz the value will be replaced by a list

Comment: @user3203406 `string.replace()` will work fine as long as he somehow turns the list into the string (e.g. `str(list)`).

Comment: @roippi see my comments it's not meaningless - it will make sense

Comment: @jedwards how to do it when fetching the value out of the dictionary?

Comment: @roippi i guess the question cant be clearer after the edit what else would you like to know?

Comment: @RomanC Guys please recheck i have edited the question and i guess it cant be any clearer!

Comment: Strange instead of giving a solution ppl are voting to downgrade the question and yet no answers at hand! It shows only one thing that people out here are only bent on building their reputation

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace the key `'/* JOB_ATR_depend */'` with a list? So you want the list to be used as a key in your dict?

If this is what you want, you can't. List is mutable and therefore not hashable and can't be used as a key in a dict

Comment: I don't think this is what he's asking at all.

Comment: What I understood was that he wants to replace the occurrences of the **key** with its **value** in a file.

Comment: yes the string inside the /* */ (comments) in this case is the key and the corresponding {} (structure) is the value.Wherever in the file the particular comment will be found it will be replaced by the structure

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new key-value pairing in the dictionary altogether, and then deleting the original key-value pairing with del.

Comment: While it is unclear what the OP is asking, I don't think it's this.

Comment: you can see that the dictionary already exists which is a comment line as the key and a structure as the value whenevr in a file the particular comment will be encountered it will be replaced by the corresponding structure